# What is the time complexity of the following loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I cannot find an answer for this online(Note the inner loop is upto `i` -
 not `n` :

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
   for(int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
     printf("foo")
   }
 }
```

For values of i = 1,2,3... , the statement will be printed 0, 1, 2 .. times so summing them will result in O(n^2). Am I correct?

Comment: You're correct.

Comment: Still O(n^2). The same way nC2 is O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

You are basically making this number of operations:

```
1 + ... + (n - 2) = 
(n - 2 + 1) * (n - 2) / 2 =
(n - 1) * (n - 2) / 2 =
(n² - 3n - 2) / 2
```

Hence

```
O((n² - 3n - 2) / 2) = 
O(n² - 3n - 2) = 
O(n²)
```

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of the code will be `O(n^2)`.

The outer loop has time complexity of `O(n)` and the inner loop runs from `0 to i`.

Hence the time complexity will be `O(n^2)`